# jSoup extract Text out of DIV tag to String

Tags: java, android, text, jsoup

I want to extract some Text out of a website and store in String.

```
<div class="textclass" id="textid" itemprop="itemtext">I want to get this Text</div>
```

What goes into the question marks?

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

                Elements text = document.select("???");

                desc = text.attr("???");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the below

```
Elements text = document.select("div");
String desc = text.text();
Log.i(".........",+desc);
```

The log after trying at my end

```
01-31 04:45:15.272: I/.........(1233): I want to get this Text
```

Edit:

You can use

```
Elements text = document.select("div[class=textclass]");
```

or using id

```
Elements text = document.select("div[id=textid]");
```

or

```
Elements text = document.select("div[itemprop=itemtext]");
```

Comment: Ohh sorry I should have said, that in the website are a few of div tags. your code won't find the right one I think.. Do you have an idea how to identify the right div?

Comment: @thankyou then you should edit your question and post the html and sepcify what you need without which no one can answer right

Comment: @thankyou use  `Elements text = document.select("div.textclass");` will find the right onw

Comment: Elements text = document.select("div.textclass"); == App Crashed Elements text = document.select("div[id=textid]"); == App Worked Thank You :) @Raghunandan

Comment: @thankyou try it here http://try.jsoup.org/ by pasting your html and trying your query. all three works. crash may be bcoz of a different reason

Comment: Elements text = document.select("div[class=textclass]"); For class that works ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Element contentDiv = doc1.select("div[id=textid]").first();
    String text=contentDiv.getElementsByTag("div").text();

    System.out.println(text); // The result
```

So get the text in the div with the id "textid" saved in the variable "text".

Comment: That would be logicly but App crahes :/